# load png images from a different directory Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to load an image from a file not in the starting directory.
So far I have:

```
BG_f = open("pictures/adventure background.png","r")
```

Later I want to blit this image to the screen, but I get:

```
screen.blit(BG_f,(0,0))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not file
```

So then I tried:

```
BG = pygame.image.load(BG_f)
```

But it only returned:

```
libpng error: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion
...
pygame.error: Error reading the PNG file.
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I've tried to look up how, but I can only find how to load images in the starting directory. I just need the most basic syntax; I'm not very fluent in python, sys, or os (if those are necessary).

Answer (score 3):

DUH I was doing it all wrong, just tried:

```
BG = pygame.image.load("pictures/adventure background.png")
```

and it worked! NVM

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
BG = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('pictures', 'background.png')).convert()
```